# How to filter records having only rank=1 in oracle without using WITH block

Tags: sql, oracle, table-alias

Created a sample table and tried filtering records having rank 1 , but its failing

Error

ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 30 Column: 3

```
CREATE TABLE exam_result (
points int,
last_name varchar(255),
first_name varchar(255) );

INSERT INTO exam_result VALUES (70, 'Emyr', 'Downes');
INSERT INTO exam_result VALUES (70, 'Dina', 'Morin');
INSERT INTO exam_result VALUES (80, 'Evie-May', 'Boyer');
INSERT INTO exam_result VALUES (60, 'Nora', 'Parkinson');
INSERT INTO exam_result VALUES (40, 'Trystan', 'Oconnor');
INSERT INTO exam_result VALUES (90, 'Eryk', 'Myers');

SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY points DESC) AS ranking,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  points
  FROM exam_result
) AS a
WHERE ranking <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `AS` keyword. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
  RANK() OVER(ORDER BY points DESC) AS ranking,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  points
  FROM exam_result
) a
WHERE ranking <= 1;
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=879e0771709020116b5f5edbeae5b29b).

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `as` keyword from your query. To alias a table, `AS` is not allowed. `AS` can be specified to give an alias to a column.

Comment: Or more specifically, Oracle does not allow `as` for table aliases, although just about every other database does.

Comment: Thanks! just fixed the wording